# Disable parent scrollbar to avoid double scrollbars

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a parent component that has `overflow: 'auto'` that I can not disable/change.

The child is an iframe that has its own scrolling, how can I disable the parent srolling from within the child to avoid the double scrollbars?

[image: by]

Comment: Use ```overflow: hidden;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the parent to

```
overflow: hidden;
```

You can do that with a dynamic css-class that you add with javascript whenever the iframe is present.

Comment: If you can't change the parents css and javascript you will have a problem.